# Changing capability type without altering plugin

Tags: capabilities

This is probably easy but if someone could help me that would be great:

I'm planning on using the "Reusable Text Blocks" plugin on several Wordpress sites.

I'm going to use this on sites that only have pages, no posts. I want to create a user role where people can edit pages, but have no ability to write posts, which is easy enough to do.

The problem is that as defined in this plugin, 'capability_type' => 'post', so if I disable posts, the user won't be able to access the text blocks either.

I can change it to 'page' of course and it works - but if I ever update this plugin, it'll overwrite, and I'll need to remember to go in and change that capability_type every time.

My question is, is there a way to reference this plugin and make that one change in functions.php? Similar to what you would do with a child theme? Basically, I would want code that says:
if this plugin is active, change capability_type to 'page'.

Here's the code: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/reusable-text-blocks/trunk/text-blocks.php

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this one by adding one plugin "user Role Manager"

Link for It https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor

Steps

1. Install user Role Manager First. and activate it.
2. Create custom role or Edit Subscriber default role to set that page
   edit permission
3. Set default role in setting as custom role if custom role created.
4. Its Done.

Comment: i'm using User Role Editor to create custom roles, which is working. what i want to do though is change a specific capability in a plugin, without interfering with the plugin itself. basically a "child plugin".

Comment: what i want to do is edit

'$args = array(
     
     'capability_type'   => 'post',
      )
    );'

and turn it into

'$args = array(
     
     'capability_type'   => 'page',
      )
    );'

but not have to change it every time the plugin updates. :P

Comment: By my suggested solution. you don't need to be worry on plugin updates. this will be saved out as part of database operation. If you looking for child plugin then also this is same solution because this second plugin work as child for your plugin. you can contact me direct for the help too. I am always open for help.